# Why is C++ not recognizing my object instantiation in main?

Tags: c++

I am getting an error C2228 in the main function. More specifically it is saying  left of empty requires a class/struct/union. I am confused because it seems like it is not recognizing my parse object in certain situations and have no clue why that is. As far as I know, I have instantiated an object so I should be able to access all public methods with the dot operator.

parse_arguments.h

```
class parse_arguments:
public:
     std::string get_model_file();
private:
     std::string m_model_file;
```

parse_arguments.cpp

```
argument_parser::argument_parser() 
: m_output_file() 
, m_model_file()
, m_norm_mode(false)
, m_learn_mode(false)
, m_input_files()
, m_nbins(16)
{}

std::string argument_parser::get_model_file()
{
    return m_model_file;
}

std::string argument_parser::get_output_file()
{
    return m_output_file;
}
```

main.cpp

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {

     normalizer_tool::argument_parser parse;

     if (!parse.parse_arguments(argc, argv)) //no error here...
     {
        return 1;
     }

/// Load the data model
    if (!parse.get_model_file.empty()) //error here c222
    {
        //do stuff here
    }

    for (auto it = parse.get_input_files.begin(); success && it != 
    parse.get_input_files.end(); it++) //error here c222
    { //do more stuff here }
```

Comment: Changing your  tag from C to C++.

Comment: Use `get_model_file().empty()`. `get_model_file` without braces is a method pointer

Comment: I suggest you reread your textbook's chapter on class definitions.

Comment: That's not a valid class definition in C++. One needs to include curly braces.

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has to many errors that I don't know where to start with.

First, the class definition's colon ":" is too much and it needs curly braces "{" and "}". Correction:

```
class parse_arguments
{
    ...
};
```

Second, missing parentheses "()" on method calls. Correction:

```
if (!parse.get_model_file().empty())
```

and:

```
for (auto it = parse.get_input_files().begin(); success && it != 
parse.get_input_files().end(); it++) ...
```

Third, recreating the input_files list multiple times during iteration, which may or may not work. This would only be safe if the input_files() method was a const method. To be safe, use instead:

```
const auto input_files = parse.get_input_files();
for (auto it = input_files.begin(); success && it != 
input_files.end(); it++) ...
```

... and so on. I hope that this helps you to get back on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the input man! I feel stupid for this mistake, I knew it was something trivial. I had a question about your last point..get_input_file() method is a const getter method: std::vector<std::string> const &argument_parser::get_input_files() const
    {
        return m_input_files;
    } This is legal right?

Comment: Yes, that should work. I wouldn't depend on that behaviour too much, though, and/or use a more modern C++ for loop, such as std::for_each().

Comment: And, of course, try to apply this, as it may help you to resolve your issue without relying on StackOverflow too much: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve